# Identifiability of a state space system

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory, system-identification

I'm trying to solve assignment 4E.5 from [this sheet](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/electrical-engineering/electrical-controls/9780132441933/models-of-linear-time-invariant-systems/ch04lev1sec9) (ship steering dynamics).
My question are: 
Do I need to perform the Laplace Transform in order to check for identifiability?
The state space model gives me a matrix $A$ and a vector $b$.
For the Laplace transform $G(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1} B + D$. I am missing $C$, $s$ and $D$.

How can I set up the equation?

Comment: Define identifiability?

Comment: Identifying the 6 parameters which appear in the matrix A and the vector b. How can that be done, only via the Laplace transform?